# Cannot run built gradle project with shadowJar NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, gradle

This should be super simple all i want to do is export this java class HelloWorld.java contained in the src/main/java default package into a runnable jar. It has one dependency joda-time and i can get shadow to build it but every time i get this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/LocalTime
        at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.joda.time.LocalTime
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 1 more
```

Heres my setup and the errors that you see are because the eclipse version of gradle is outdated. Additionally the commands i used to build it are `gradle clean`, and then `gradle shadow` while in the root directory of the project.

[image]

Finnaly here is my build.gradle and my HelloWorld.java

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '5.2.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

shadowJar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'HelloWorld'
    }
    configurations = [project.configurations.compile]
    baseName = 'HelloWorld'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    shadow "joda-time:joda-time:2.2"
    shadow "junit:junit:4.12"
}
```

---

```
import org.joda.time.LocalTime;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        LocalTime currentTime = new LocalTime();
        System.out.println("The current local time is: " + currentTime);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
dependencies {
    implementation "joda-time:joda-time:2.2"
    implementation "junit:junit:4.12"
}
```

Why you are using joda time? Why version 2.2? Look at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time
Are you sure if java.time package is inadequate?

Comment: i am just trying to build my project with a dependency i dont care about the version or what i could use otherwise. I intend to scale the solution to a bigger program im working on but i cant even get it working with this super simple one.